# Need to toogle visibility based on tab IsSelected, Grid is in shell project and tab is in another module, will datatrigger work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

In Shell module, where the grid need to be collapsed based on tab selected in other module, i think it should work, as on initializing shell, it will integrate tab contained module to itself shell, but How? with eventAggregator we can do that, but need to keep View logic in View itself

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>                    
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ManualTab, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infra:RegionName.ScriptSelector}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing a message between the ViewModels using MvvmLight's Messenger service, or having a shared ViewModel which both View's VM's will inherit from, and each View will use the 'isSelected' property for it's own uses

Comment: He's using Prism, not MvvmLight ;-)

Comment: my bad, missed that part

Comment: Messenger service or eventAggregator will solve it, but what about xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Your shell has its own `ShellViewModel`, I suppose, so that can communicate with the tab's view model through `EventAggregator`. Then show or hide the tab by binding to a property on the `ShellViewModel` that gets changed from the event subscription...

Comment: is it Not possible through xaml only?

Comment: eventAggregator will solve the problem but i was looking for xaml

Comment: can you expand on _why_ you want it in xaml? Anything that prevents you from doing it in the view model?  If you find a binding expression that works, it will be rather fragile and you'll be constantly fixing it. A solution in the view model will just work, and providing information to the view is exactly the view model's job.

Comment: what i understood in xaml visual tree lookup is, whenever the element is search inside usercontrol or window, it is bottomtop lookup, by this logic datatrigger should work. was looking the xaml logic for less c# code.okay leave it, bottom line is application should work